# How change the color of the individual button from gray to black onClick and how to assign the "key" prop on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, button, chessboard.js

How change the color of the individual button from gray to black onClick and how to assign the "key" prop on React?

**I get this message "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." even though I already assign the key. And how to change the color of the individual buttons from gray to black (not all of the buttons). Here's my code. I'm using react.**

Square.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Square(props) {
    const square = {
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px",
        color:"yellow",
        backgroundColor: props.shade
    };
    return (
      <button className={"square " + props.shade}
      onClick={props.onClick}
      style={square}
      key={props.value}>{props.value}
      </button>
    );
  
}
```

Board.js

```
import Square from './Square.js';
import React from 'react';

export default class Board extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
          this.state ={
            temp:"",    
            colorB:"black",
        }    
      }  

    color=()=> {
        this.setState({ temp: this.state.colorB})
        this.setState({ colorB: this.state.temp})
    }  
    renderSquare(key, squareShade) {
        return <Square 
        shade = {squareShade}
        onClick={this.color}
        />
    }
  
    render() {
      const board = [];
      for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        const squareRows = [];
        for(let j = 0; j < 8; j++){
          const squareShade = (isEven(i) && isEven(j)) || (!isEven(i) && !isEven(j))? this.state.temp : this.state.colorB;
          squareRows.push(<Square 
            shade = {squareShade}
            onClick={this.color}
            key={(i*8 + j).toString()} //the key
            value={(i*8 + j).toString()}
            />);
        }
        board.push(<div className="board-row">{squareRows}</div>)
      }
  
      return (
        <div>
            {board}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  
  function isEven(num){
    return num % 2 === 0
  }

/*
Some of the codes are referenced from: https://www.techighness.com/post/develop-two-player-chess-game-with-react-js/
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though is easy to put a `i` inside the `key` attribute, **never** use the `index` value as key. The index is not unique and can conflict **between components**.

use something like `key={squareRows.id}` instead. Provide some unique id **without** the index value.